# Link to Resource from a Resource file

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have a global resource file: ContactDetails.resx. In here are addresses and contact information used around the website.

I also have a contact page listing all the contact details, but changing depending on language. So on the UK website, the UK contact details appear at the top, whereas on the French website the French details will appear at the top.

Is there a way to nest resources, referencing a resource value from within the value of a different resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a resource value doesn't exist in your French resource file, but does in your Default resource file, the system will automatically get the value from the default resource file.

So if your localization is set to `fr`, and your call is something like:

```
Resources.ContactDetails.Telephone
```

And Telephone doesn't exist in `ContactDetails.fr.resx` then it will get the Telephone value from `ContactDetails.resx`

---

If all the values are to be displayed on the page, but in a different order depending on the localization I would recommend not storing these in a resource file. The resource file variations are for changes in language, not to change layout of data.

Instead I would recommend to store these in the database, and have 3 literal controls on the page like:

```
<asp:literal id="ltl1stTelephone" runat="server" />
<asp:literal id="ltl2ndTelephone" runat="server" />
<asp:literal id="ltl3rdTelephone" runat="server" />
```

Then depending on the localization, specify which values should be assigned to each control.

```
if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "fr"){
   .........
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm asking. Basically one resource file is providing the structure of the page (possibly not the best practice I know). This loads which order the contact details appear. However, I do not want to store the contact details themselves inside this file as a change to one telephone number would mean a change in lots of other places. Instead I want to have another location which holds all the contact details, referenced from the first resource file.

Comment: Thinking about it, I wonder if resource files are the correct method to go about this... how would you achieve this?

Comment: So you're storing HTML code in a Resource string value? This probably isn't the best method. You could use a different CSS file if its the french localization? That would probably work better. Or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: Nah I think you've got it. I'm trying to be lazy/efficient and keep a global list of contact details, then list them in different ways. Say I had a Global contacts.resx file that holds the contact details as formatted and displayed in each language (ie. contacts.resx: [PhoneEN:01252 134567] [PhoneFR:+33 2 12 34 56 78]; contacts.fr.resx: [PhoneEN:+44 1252 134567] [PhoneFR: 02 12 34 56 78]).

If I then loaded these onto the page (wrapped in divs lets say), how could I use CSS to re-order them? I could do it if I used a seperate ascx file to hold the order of each, but CSS would be much cleaner

Comment: That makes sense, I probably won't use a complete database table (probably XML) but the concept is certainly valid. Thanks.